# Difficulty of graph coloring and independent set?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, parameterized-complexity, graph-colouring, subset-sum, independent-set

Given a graph on $n$ vertices it is **strongly** $NP$-complete to decide it is $3$-colorable while it is easy to decide it is $n$-colorable.

1. Is there a parsimonious reduction from **SUBSET-SUM** to **GRAPH-3-COLORABILITY** or **K-INDEPENDENT SET**?
2. Is there a deterministic reduction from **GRAPH-3-COLORABILITY** to **UNAMBIGUOUS-GRAPH-3-COLORABILITY** or **K-INDEPENDENT SET** to **UNMAMBIGUOUS-K-INDEPENDENT SET**?

Comment: This is a bit of a strange question. Polynomial time separations can be crossed by changing computer architecture, so I think you'd have to be very specific about what context you want a polynomial separation to hold on.

Comment: Pragmatically speaking, a polynomial time separation in a cryptographic scheme is a sign that the scheme doesn't work for usual purposes.

Comment: I think it's better to stick to a single question, not a list of questions. I also think it's better to start a new question rather than change an old one into something completely different.

Comment: In planar graphs 6 coloring is trivial, and 4 coloring is doable in polynomial time, but 3 coloring is hard. So I don't see if there is any point to define a function like f(n), as for example in complete graphs it should be at least n and in planar graphs it should be a constant.

Comment: Simplified posting.